# build rejected by apple

Tags: iphone, build, crash, app-store

1. The app was been uploaded to App Store but it was been rejected with following crash logs
   can someone provide me a solution for the problem.
2. I can't understand the reason for a crash .
3. The app on testing run smoothly without any crash on iPhone 7.1.2.

please look in the issue any help will be appreciated.

```
                {"bundleID":"com.walkover.voip91","app_name":"Phone91","bug_type":"109","name":"Phone91","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.2 (11D257)","version":"1.1.0 (1.1.0)"}
                Incident Identifier: 18F00B49-CB7D-429D-877E-0459988959BD
                CrashReporter Key:   99f9caadfd48c4739585b7383898f343220c933c
                Hardware Model:      xxx
                Process:             Phone91 [168]
                Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/1DB8837E-9F6C-4F49-8CB1-3DE83ECABDED/Phone91.app/Phone91
                Identifier:          com.walkover.vo
                Version:             1.1.0 (1.1.0)
                Code Type:           ARM (Native)
                Parent Process:      launchd [1]

                Date/Time:           2014-08-21 08:04:37.228 -0700
                OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
                Report Version:      104

                Exception Type:  00000020
                Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
                Highlighted Thread:  0

                Application Specific Information:
                com.walkover.voip91 failed to launch in time

                Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.820 (user 2.820, system 0.000), 4% CPU 
                Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.182, 0% CPU

                Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
                Thread 0:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b63faa0 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
                1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b58cd3d _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 173
                2   Phone91                         0x00032c01 0x4000 + 191489
                3   Phone91                         0x000211e9 0x4000 + 119273
                4   Phone91                         0x000119df 0x4000 + 55775
                5   UIKit                           0x32d64c9d -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 273
                6   UIKit                           0x32d645ef -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1607
                7   UIKit                           0x32d5eca5 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 717
                8   UIKit                           0x32cfac73 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3547
                9   UIKit                           0x32cf9dd5 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 69
                10  UIKit                           0x32d5e3e1 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 613
                11  GraphicsServices                0x35331b53 _PurpleEventCallback + 607
                12  GraphicsServices                0x3533173b PurpleEventCallback + 31
                13  CoreFoundation                  0x3048e805 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 33
                14  CoreFoundation                  0x3048e79f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 343
                15  CoreFoundation                  0x3048cf6b __CFRunLoopRun + 1403
                16  CoreFoundation                  0x303f7725 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
                17  CoreFoundation                  0x303f7507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
                18  UIKit                           0x32d5d607 -[UIApplication _run] + 759
                19  UIKit                           0x32d5886d UIApplicationMain + 1133
                20  Phone91                         0x0000d93f 0x4000 + 39231
                21  Phone91                         0x00009dd4 0x4000 + 24020

                Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
                Thread 1:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b63f804 kevent64 + 24
                1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b58e051 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 229
                2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b5882df _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

                Thread 2:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b652c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
                1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
                2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7ad8 start_wqthread + 4

                Thread 3:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b63fa50 mach_msg_trap + 20
                1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b63f849 mach_msg + 37
                2   CoreFoundation                  0x3048e5e5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
                3   CoreFoundation                  0x3048cd05 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
                4   CoreFoundation                  0x303f7725 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
                5   CoreFoundation                  0x303f7507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
                6   Foundation                      0x30deb493 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 251
                7   Foundation                      0x30e3c255 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 77
                8   Phone91                         0x0006d12c 0x4000 + 430380
                9   Foundation                      0x30eada0b __NSThread__main__ + 1059
                10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b9957 _pthread_body + 139
                11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b98c7 _pthread_start + 99
                12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7ae4 thread_start + 4

                Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
                Thread 4:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b63fa50 mach_msg_trap + 20
                1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b63f849 mach_msg + 37
                2   CoreFoundation                  0x3048e5e5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
                3   CoreFoundation                  0x3048cd05 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
                4   CoreFoundation                  0x303f7725 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
                5   CoreFoundation                  0x303f7507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
                6   Foundation                      0x30e3823d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 317
                7   Foundation                      0x30eada0b __NSThread__main__ + 1059
                8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b9957 _pthread_body + 139
                9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b98c7 _pthread_start + 99
                10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7ae4 thread_start + 4

                Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
                Thread 5:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b652434 __select + 20
                1   CoreFoundation                  0x304924df __CFSocketManager + 483
                2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b9957 _pthread_body + 139
                3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b98c7 _pthread_start + 99
                4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7ae4 thread_start + 4

                Thread 6:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b652c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
                1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
                2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7ad8 start_wqthread + 4

                Thread 7:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b652c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
                1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
                2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7ad8 start_wqthread + 4

                Thread 8:
                0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b652c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
                1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
                2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b6b7ad8 start_wqthread + 4

                No thread state (register information) available
```

Comment: We have no access to it. But: Try to install the built .ipa on your own device and see what happens.

Comment: We can not open your crash log, because it is in your account. Please post a symbolized version of your crash log in you question.

Comment: The screenshot of log also fine :)\

Comment: @Ramshad a symbolized version will tell more that just a screenshot. But yes it will tell us more then nothing.